# Upgrade Debian Squeeze to Stretch

Tags: linux, command-line, debian, apt

Doing `apt-get update` gets the following errors:

```
Ign http://security.debian.org squeeze/updates Release.gpg
Ign http://security.debian.org/ squeeze/updates/contrib Translation-en
Ign http://security.debian.org/ squeeze/updates/contrib Translation-en_GB
Ign http://security.debian.org/ squeeze/updates/main Translation-en
Ign http://security.debian.org/ squeeze/updates/main Translation-en_GB
Ign http://security.debian.org/ squeeze/updates/non-free Translation-en
Ign http://security.debian.org/ squeeze/updates/non-free Translation-en_GB
Ign http://security.debian.org squeeze/updates Release
Ign http://security.debian.org squeeze/updates/main Sources
Ign http://security.debian.org squeeze/updates/contrib Sources
Ign http://security.debian.org squeeze/updates/non-free Sources
Ign http://security.debian.org squeeze/updates/main amd64 Packages
Ign http://security.debian.org squeeze/updates/contrib amd64 Packages
Ign http://security.debian.org squeeze/updates/non-free amd64 Packages
Err http://security.debian.org squeeze/updates/main Sources
  404  Not Found [IP: 2001:a78:5:1:216:35ff:fe7f:6ceb 80]
Err http://security.debian.org squeeze/updates/contrib Sources
  404  Not Found [IP: 2001:a78:5:1:216:35ff:fe7f:6ceb 80]
Err http://security.debian.org squeeze/updates/non-free Sources
  404  Not Found [IP: 2001:a78:5:1:216:35ff:fe7f:6ceb 80]
Err http://security.debian.org squeeze/updates/main amd64 Packages
  404  Not Found [IP: 2001:a78:5:1:216:35ff:fe7f:6ceb 80]
Err http://security.debian.org squeeze/updates/contrib amd64 Packages
  404  Not Found [IP: 2001:a78:5:1:216:35ff:fe7f:6ceb 80]
Err http://security.debian.org squeeze/updates/non-free amd64 Packages
  404  Not Found [IP: 2001:a78:5:1:216:35ff:fe7f:6ceb 80]
25% [Connecting to ftp.de.debian.org (141.76.2.4)]^C
root@ks3309152:/# nano /etc/apt/sources.list
root@ks3309152:/# nano /etc/apt/sources.list.backup
root@ks3309152:/# nano /etc/apt/sources.list
root@ks3309152:/# apt-get update
Ign http://debian.mirrors.ovh.net squeeze Release.gpg
Ign http://debian.mirrors.ovh.net/debian/ squeeze/main Translation-en
Ign http://security.debian.org squeeze/updates Release.gpg
Ign http://debian.mirrors.ovh.net/debian/ squeeze/main Translation-en_GB
Ign http://security.debian.org/ squeeze/updates/main Translation-en
Ign http://security.debian.org/ squeeze/updates/main Translation-en_GB
Ign http://debian.mirrors.ovh.net squeeze Release
Ign http://debian.mirrors.ovh.net squeeze/main Sources
Ign http://security.debian.org squeeze/updates Release
Ign http://debian.mirrors.ovh.net squeeze/main amd64 Packages
Ign http://security.debian.org squeeze/updates/main Sources
Ign http://security.debian.org squeeze/updates/main amd64 Packages
Err http://security.debian.org squeeze/updates/main Sources
  404  Not Found [IP: 2001:a78:5:1:216:35ff:fe7f:6ceb 80]
Err http://security.debian.org squeeze/updates/main amd64 Packages
  404  Not Found [IP: 2001:a78:5:1:216:35ff:fe7f:6ceb 80]
Err http://debian.mirrors.ovh.net squeeze/main Sources
  404  Not Found [IP: 2001:41d0:202:100:213:32:5:7 80]
Err http://debian.mirrors.ovh.net squeeze/main amd64 Packages
  404  Not Found [IP: 2001:41d0:202:100:213:32:5:7 80]
W: Failed to fetch http://debian.mirrors.ovh.net/debian/dists/squeeze/main/source/Sources.gz  404  Not Found [IP: 2001:41d0:202:100:213:32:5:7 80]

W: Failed to fetch http://debian.mirrors.ovh.net/debian/dists/squeeze/main/binary-amd64/Packages.gz  404  Not Found [IP: 2001:41d0:202:100:213:32:5:7 80]

W: Failed to fetch http://security.debian.org/dists/squeeze/updates/main/source/Sources.gz  404  Not Found [IP: 2001:a78:5:1:216:35ff:fe7f:6ceb 80]

W: Failed to fetch http://security.debian.org/dists/squeeze/updates/main/binary-amd64/Packages.gz  404  Not Found [IP: 2001:a78:5:1:216:35ff:fe7f:6ceb 80]

E: Some index files failed to download, they have been ignored, or old ones used instead.
```

I realize I am 3 major versions away from the current, what do I need to do from here to upgrade to Debian Stretch properly based from the errors I get?

Comment: @dsstorefile added more info

Comment: Comment out all the urls in sources.list that are unreachable.

Comment: @n8te well it appears the (2) only URLs are both unreachable

Answer (score 2):

I'd just jump straight to wheezy, but if you want to run updates for squeeze beforehand you can change your `sources.list` to point to `archive.debian.org`.

```
deb http://archive.debian.org/debian-security squeeze/updates main
deb http://archive.debian.org/debian squeeze main
deb http://archive.debian.org/debian squeeze-lts main
deb http://archive.debian.org/debian squeeze-proposed-updates main
```

Comment: I did that and now I get:

`W: GPG error: http://archive.debian.org squeeze/updates Release: The following signatures were invalid: KEYEXPIRED 1520281423
W: GPG error: http://archive.debian.org squeeze Release: The following signatures were invalid: KEYEXPIRED 1520281423 KEYEXPIRED 1501892461
E: Release file expired, ignoring http://archive.debian.org/debian/dists/squeeze-lts/Release (invalid since 766d 20h 12min 50s)
`

Comment: Ok now when I try `apt-get upgrade` it says `0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.`

Comment: I tried again.. now this is what I get `WARNING: The following packages cannot be authenticated!
  base-files tzdata`

Comment: It isn't but is it safe to skip it

Comment: that was before I commented out `squeeze-lts main`

Comment: it appears `base-files` `tzdata` needs to be updated after commenting out `squeeze-lts main`

Answer (score 1):

I think this way you can upgrade.

**First upgrade Debian Squeeze To Wheezy.**

[How To Upgrade Debian Squeeze To Wheezy](https://www.howtoforge.com/how-to-upgrade-debian-squeeze-to-wheezy)

**Then upgrade Debian Wheezy to Jessie.**

[How to upgrade Debian Wheezy to Jessie safely](https://www.howtoforge.com/tutorial/how-to-upgrade-debian-wheezy-to-jessie-stable-release/)

**Finally upgrade Debian Jessie to 9 Stretch.**

[How to Upgrade Debian 8 (Jessie) to 9 (Stretch) safely](https://www.howtoforge.com/tutorial/how-to-upgrade-debian-8-jessie-to-9-stretch/)

Comment: Sorry but I'm using command line only, no GUI

Comment: Try this command --> sudo apt-get dist-upgrade

Comment: I got this `0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded`

Comment: I would advise you to update from squeeze to wheezy first and then from wheezy to jessie  finally jessie to Stretch.

Comment: Well yeah but I get those errors in the description

Answer (score 1):

As others have said you need to go Squeeze -> Wheezy -> Jessie -> Stretch.

To solve your package signing issues I'd manually install the `debian-keyring` from the release you're upgrading too first (Downloadable via [packages.debian.org](https://packages.debian.org/search?keywords=debian-keyring)). (`dpkg -i debian-keyring_version.deb` to install)

Then follow the instructions in the release notes for each release:

- [Wheezy](https://www.debian.org/releases/wheezy/amd64/release-notes/ch-upgrading.en.html)
- [Jessie](https://www.debian.org/releases/jessie/amd64/release-notes/ch-upgrading.en.html)
- [Stretch](https://www.debian.org/releases/stretch/amd64/release-notes/ch-upgrading.en.html)

Comment: Generally a good idea with the keyring, but `contains ununderstood data member control.tar.xz, giving up` ... the package format has changed (.xz support added).